# Datatables clear input filters

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I am using datatables v1.10.11 and Jquery v 2.2.0

I have one table with two input search filters;

```
<input type="text" id="myInputTextField1" class="form-control"> <!--search one-->

<input type="text" id="myInputTextField2" class="form-control"> <!--search two-->
```

My datatable JS;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable({});
}); 

$('#myInputTextField1').keyup(function(){
  table.search($(this).val()).draw() ;
})

$('#myInputTextField2').keyup(function(){
  table.search($(this).val()).draw() ;
})
```

The search is working fine, no issues.

How would I incorporate a simple button that when clicked, will clear both input fields and reset the table to it's default state? For example;

```
<button type="button" id="test">Clear Filters</button>

<table id="example">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>COLUMN 1</th>
    <th>COLUMN 2</th>
    <th>COLUMN 3</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>ROW 1</td>
    <td>ROW 1</td>
    <td>ROW 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>ROW 2</td>
    <td>ROW 2</td>
    <td>ROW 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>ROW 3</td>
    <td>ROW 3</td>
    <td>ROW 3</td>
  </tr>  
</tbody>
</table>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To reset a search filter, just call `search()` again with an empty string. Similarly you can clear the value of an input by setting its value to an empty string. Try this:

```
$('#test').click(function() {
    $('#myInputTextField1, #myInputTextField2').val('');
    table.search('').draw(); //required after
});
```

[**Working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/4rvmtv7d/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<button type="button" id="test" class="btn btn-primary">Clear Filters</button>

  $('#test').click(function () {
              $('input:text').val('');
              var datatableVariable = $('#tblBusinessDev').dataTable();
              datatableVariable.fnFilterClear();
              $('#tblBusinessDev tfoot input').val('').change();
          });


//filter code

jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oApi.fnFilterClear = function (oSettings) {
              var i, iLen;

              /* Remove global filter */
              oSettings.oPreviousSearch.sSearch = "";

              /* Remove the text of the global filter in the input boxes */
              if (typeof oSettings.aanFeatures.f != 'undefined') {
                  var n = oSettings.aanFeatures.f;
                  for (i = 0, iLen = n.length ; i < iLen ; i++) {
                      $('input', n[i]).val('');
                  }
              }

              /* Remove the search text for the column filters - NOTE - if you have input boxes for these
               * filters, these will need to be reset
               */
              for (i = 0, iLen = oSettings.aoPreSearchCols.length ; i < iLen ; i++) {
                  oSettings.aoPreSearchCols[i].sSearch = "";
              }

              /* Redraw */
              oSettings.oApi._fnReDraw(oSettings);
          };
```